# Handling Read Timeout caused by network fluctuation

Tags: java, networking

I am having a java application which reads the records(count of records to b read is configurable) from the sql 2008 database.
And process them and this is done in a infinite loop and only stops when application is stopped manually.

The issue im facing here is that the application stops fetching records from database when I get Read Time out error.
And I guess this is because of the network fluctuations.

The code for reading from the db is written in try catch block.so when the error occurs it gets logged but also stops.
I have no idea how to handle such situation and make the application run continuously in spite of the error.
Please let me know how can I handle the error such that my application continues to run.

Comment: how about saving the cursor, and if the catch block code is called, rerun the function from the position of the cursor?

Comment: If you add more of your code, the answers could improve :)

Answer (score 0):

While reading you should store the information on where you stopped and set the connection up again after it failed to continue.

Like this:

```
boolean programRuns = true; // set this to false at the end

public void doMyStuff() {
    int myLastPosition = 0;
    while(programRuns) {
         try {
             Connection con = /* open your connection */
             String statement = /* your statement */ + "WHERE id > " + myLastPosition;
             PreparedStatement pstmt = /* prepare your statement */
             while(true) {
                 ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                 myLastPosition = rs.getInt("id");
                 /* do whatever you want with the result */
             }
         } catch (Exception ex) { /* handle the exception */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: @sonu If my solution solved your problem please mark it as correct (with the hook on the left of the answer). If not, please post the correct answer by yourself.